# Separate a Mesh into several small meshes using Python

Tags: bisect, python

I would like to separate a mesh into smaller individual meshes using Python script. The whole mesh as shown in the picture has 500 m in length, and I would like to set up a series of parallel Planes of slicing each 5m so I can have hundreds of individual parts.

Pictures below show :
1)- Whole mesh
2)- example of separate parts
3)- example of parallel bisecting planes that will be used to cut the mesh and make individual parts

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118884/python-bisect-mesh-into-n-parts-without-separate-loose   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133086/slicing-an-object-in-4-parts