# Separate Mesh into parts based on spacial geometry and not linked-rule

Tags: python

I was able to run a python script that cuts my mesh into several meshes based on the following thread :  [Bisect mesh into n parts, without separate 'LOOSE'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118884/python-bisect-mesh-into-n-parts-without-separate-loose). However, some of these parts should still be separated based on the fact that they are spatially not linked.

The images below explain the issue. Basically, instead of one mesh that encompasses the 5 geometries, I would like 5 separated meshes in my scene.

I tried to different selection tools but I couldn't get the desired effect

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

[image]com/JAOQt.jpg

[image]

Comment: Please don't ask what is basically the same question twice https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237993/separate-a-mesh-into-several-small-meshes-using-python  , instead edit any extra information into previous. Appears to me  the regular separate by LOOSE parts operator will turn the last mesh shown above into 5 parts.

Comment: oh sorry for that ! will do for next time. At first, Separate by LOOSE didn't really work but after correcting the mesh (merge vertices by distance), I get clean separation. Thanks a lot BatFinger !!